# PHP scripts do not get interpreted on Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I hosted an HTML page on "Google Drive" and it works correctly.

I loaded a PHP script there.  But the PHP script does not get interpreted.

Why is Google drive not evaluating my PHP script?

Comment: @DannyBeckett - [Google says it is](https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AMXBENXlnYmJISlE/GoogleDriveHosting.html). However, PHP scripts are not supported, only HTML, JS & CSS.

Comment: You're right! Removed my DV too.

Answer (score 3):

Google Drive is NOT a web server.  It won't run PHP files.

Google supports hosting simple HTML-based sites on Google Drive, as long as it does not involve server-side scripting and shared to Public.

Reference: [Google Drive Hosting](https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AMXBENXlnYmJISlE/GoogleDriveHosting.html)